# Cross platform Mobile SDK with react native for IOS and Android

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, sdk

I am beginner to react native. Please forgive if it is a very basic question. I have a Javascript client library which I want to write for both IOS and Android also. Instead of writing separately. would like to know if I could create such libraries using React Native.Like writing the library in react native and convert it to IOS or Android compatible. like adding the dependency in the existing Native application like **Android** or **Swift** codebase.

I checked with many articles where everything is explaining about integrating the react native app to native application with View but what I am looking for is different I need to integrate that library like dependency.Kindly help me with this.

Thanks in Advance.